# Browse an Angular app inside a WebBrowser control

Tags: node.js, angular, winforms, webbrowser-control, angular-cli

It's kind of a strange scenario, but I want to view our Angular application inside the `WebBrowser` control of a WinForm application.

The Angular application is running locally with `npm run start` or `ng serve`, this works quite well in all of the browsers on my system (Chrome, FF, Edge, IE).

When accessing the site (http://localhost:4200/login) via the `WebBrowser` control I continuously retrieve a status 404.

I've tried searching for some docs on the matter and the accessibility of the Angular webserver, but couldn't find anything. My best guess is the site is running inside some kind of node.js process and the WinForm application isn't able to access this, or do proper routing to the Angular application, but I can't find any sources to this theory.

You might be wondering why I'm trying to get this to work, well, I want to see if the `Navigated`-event still occurs in our new Angular application, because it appears this isn't the case, where this event WAS triggered in our AngularJS application. So it's just a test/poc application.

On a sidenote: The `WebBrowser` control IS able to connect to the AngularJS application we have (also running locally), but this one is running via IIS Express. That's why I thought it might be a webserver/routing issue.

Some more details on what I've built so far.

The **Form1.Designer.cs**

```
// All of the other WinForm stuff
private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser v2Browser;
```

The Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        v2Browser.Navigate("http://localhost:4200/login");
    }

    private void V2BrowserNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write($"v2 has navigated to `{e.Url}`." + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

NG command to start the webserver

```
> ng serve --watch --sourcemap=false

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
Date: 2017-10-23T14:43:54.585Z
Hash: 54a4c907e66e478979a5
Time: 26736ms
```

Request (captured via Fiddler)

```
GET http://localhost:4200/login HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
If-None-Match: W/"654-dUFWfqPxZMcM1Ej8ZbZ0A8+KsiA"
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response (via Fiddler)

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 144
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2017 14:44:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /login</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

So it's not much of an error I'm receiving, just a 404 response.

Comment: Normally in this kind of situation bootstrap angular app in the iframe or web broswer control is a pain. if you cannot bootstrap automatically, you can do it manually or you can use systemjs build and confuguration if webpack build is not working for you. if you can post the actual error and how you are trying to bootstrap the app I can suggest something in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering I didn't get access to the hosted application via `ng serve` I decided to just build the application via `ng build` and point a new IIS website to the output folder.

This works like a charm, so it solves my problem but isn't really what I was looking for.

After having worked with the IIS site a bit, I also discovered the solution to my problem is using the `--host` parameter in the CLI.

```
ng serve --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

Will run the site locally and you will be able to connect to it by not using `localhost`.  Solved my problem!